# How do I convert a type i made into String for textarea in java?

Tags: types, textarea, jtextarea

When I tried to convert my array into String, it always tells me

> error: no suitable method found for toString(sample)

Sample is the type that I made for my arraylist. Is there any way to fix this?

```
          sample relief=javacup.relief();
            textarea.append(Arrays.toString(relief));
            textarea.append("\n");
```

Comment: Are you able to share some code?

Comment: String is not a primitive type though